# 404 error due to .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I copied our live project to a sub directory. But when i am trying to run it, It's showing 404 error. I did required changes in .htaccess file, But its still showing /Publish/index.php page not found.

I checked file and folder is exist and have 755 permissions.
Don't know why its showing 404 error.

Here is my .htaccess file code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /var/www/site/serp/httpdocs/
RewriteRule ^robots.txt /robots-development.txt
RewriteRule ^robots.txt /robots-development.txt
RewriteRule ^index.htm([^/]+)/$ /Publish/index.php?lang_value=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /Publish/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.htm$ /Publish/index.php [NC]
```

NOTE:- I cant restart apache server. So i can't add anything in apache conf files.

Comment: Provide your file structure.

Comment: Here is my .htaccess file   http://pastebin.com/cbKZdi2F

Comment: Are you sure the absolute folder url is /var/www/site/serp/httpdocs/? The error is likely caused by this line since its rewriting the base but cant find anything so it throws a 404.

Comment: actually it's a long path, But i make it small using links. So when i type PWD in folder it's showing this folder url. But actually its a big URL. So is there any problem i put shrinked URL?

Comment: I also tried with big URL, But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteBase` seems wrong as it should be relative path from your `DocumentRoot`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-development.txt [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.htm([^/]+)/$ Publish/index.php?lang_value=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ Publish/index.php [NC,L]
```